# google maps API duplicate view in zoom 1

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I tried to use zoom 1 or 2 to see only the continents I can see the screen duplicate for several time and the continents are repeat in screen. 
( the screen split to 3 frames )

Can I control on the screen and show the continents only once and not duplicate ?

Regards,

Yossi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is normal; it is how the Google map deals with very low zoom levels. I also start my map at a worldwide zoom to show all of the continents. Another factor is the user's screen resolution. I originally started my map at zoom level 3, but it turned out that some users, with low screen resolution settings, couldn't see everything that is placed on my map when it first loads. Because of that, I now start at zoom 2. Users with higher screen resolutions just understand that they may see a duplicating run of the world map at the edges.

Comment: I need to see two zoom one of the continents and other of country so I want to see the continent just once and not duplicate , is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a hack! [Here's an example for zoom 0](http://jsbin.com/ijojip/2/edit#preview) (when viewing the page, zoom out once).

The mechanism is to listen for zoom changes and at the low zoom enable two absolute positioned gray divs (one on each side) to cover the "duplicates". A fixed width map is practically necessary. And you'll need new pairs of divs for zooms 1 and 2.

The huge drawback is the controls get covered by the divs, and placing them in the center is ugly (I tried it). You could cover up only the right half of the map, but the effect also does not look good. (see here http://jsbin.com/ijojip/3/edit#preview )

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      if(map.getZoom() == 0) {
        document.getElementById("leftcover").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("rightcover").style.display = "block";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("leftcover").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("rightcover").style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    #leftcover { position: absolute; height: 100%; background-color: #e5e3df; left: 0px; width: 128px; z-index: 2; display: none }
    #rightcover { position: absolute; height: 100%; background-color: #e5e3df; left: 384px; width: 128px; z-index: 2; display: none }
```